# How to maximize $a^2 + \delta^2(s-a)^2$ by inspection?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I need to maximize:

> $a^2 + \delta^2(s-a)^2$

where:

$\delta\in(0,1)$ and $0\le a \le s$.

The solution in my text simply states:

> Since $\delta^2 < 1$ , the maximum occurs when $a=s$.

I can see that $\delta^2 < 1$ is true, but I don't get how knowing that enables us to immediately conclude that the maximum must be when $a=s$.

I actually tried to find the maximum by using the first order condition for a maximum (and later going to compare it at the endpoints i.e. $0$ and $s$) but end up with a complicated looking expression, so I aborted it and had a look at the solution instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given particular values of $a$ and $\delta$, it is obvious that the expression is maximised when $s$ is as large as possible.

If you are given particular values of $a$ and $s$, it is obvious that the expression is maximised when $\delta$ is as large as possible.

If you are given particular values of $s$ and $\delta$, it is not obvious at first what needs to happen about $a$. So consider the two extreme values.

If $a=0$ then the expression takes the value $\delta^2 s^2$.

If $a=s$ then the expression takes the value $s^2$.

The expression is quadratic in $a$ with a positive coefficient of $a^2$, so does not have a local maximum. It must either have a local minimum between the two extremes or a local minimum elsewhere. The maximum values must therefore be achieved at one of the extremes.

So which is greater: $\delta^2 s^2$ or $s^2$?

$\delta^2<1$ means that $\delta^2 s^2<s^2$

Comment: Isn't the expression of the quadratic in $a$ have a positive coefficient of $1+\delta^2$?